# What is the best way to sync iCal calendars between multiple Macs on the same network?

Tags: mac-osx, apple, ical

I have to sync iCal on all the computers without having a MobileMe account, I would like it to be "live" because the co-workers have to see the changes right away on their screens, they also need to be able to edit and stay sync on the rest of the LAN.

There isn't a server available - so a server solution such as iCal Server won't work.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Google Calendar + CalDav](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99358#ical).

We use it as our calendar for our business, and it's solid. iCal integration is not 100% (no tasks, each calendar is a new account), but the most important parts are even better than iCal Server IMO. Having google email or SMS you a few hours before a meeting is especially nice.

Comment: Google Calendar kicks ass and is really easy to use !

Comment: Agreed.  I sync iCal on two Macs, plus an iPhone; works great and any old web browser will work in a pinch.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use [iCal server](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/ical-server.html) which is apart of Mac OS X Server.

Or

Publish iCal calendars with local WebDAV server.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Zimbra Open Source Edition](http://www.zimbra.com/community/downloads.html).  It supports CalDAV for Leopard clients as well as address book Sync.  You won't need to setup a dedicated server since it supports Mac OSX as a server platform or you could run it under a Linux virtual machine with VirtualBox/VMWare Fusion/Parallels and make it portable.

Answer (score 0):

I up-voted for Google Calendar + CalDAV as I use that for my personal calendars and it works well for me, but I don't use To Dos/Tasks at all so I don't miss that functionality.

I wouldn't suggest using Mac OS X Server's iCal Server (also CalDAV-powered) anyway as there are still a few odd bugs w/group calendars, permissions, re-sycing when disconnected, etc. Also, it really requires an Open Directory setup with the workstations bound and don't expect to be able to invite anyone to meetings if they aren't in Open Directory. Overall  it's okay, but probably more work than you're looking for.

One other suggestion is [BusyMac's BusySync](http://www.busymac.com/busysync/index.html). Shareware and does a great job of sharing & syncing calendars on a local network.